# No detail applying to my model when adding complex textures

Tags: texturing, unreal-engine

Disclaimer:

I am very new to blender and have gone through multiple tutorial series on 3D Modelling, Animation and Sculpting.

This is the only source of any knowledge I have in blender.

I don't know how to texture inside of blender and how it manages that space at all.

For all texturing that I need to do, I just port my model over to Substance Designer and continue from there.

My issue may very well be a beginner mistake and so please do bear with me on this.

Issue:

I have created a fairly standard low-poly model in blender, and in the attempt to texture it, I ran into a few issues.

Here are the screenshots of my model in the Object and Edit Modes:

[image: Object Mode]

[image]

Now to test any texturing on this I simply raw exported the model as fbx from blender to Unreal. From there I tried on a Grass Material in the Unreal Starter Contents package as a test.

None of the detail of my texture shows on the surface of my model. Only the Base Color and Reflectivity seems to be mapped onto it.

[image]

I do think this has much to do with the amount of vertices on my model and the lack of many subdivisions, but I don't know for sure.

Please advise any steps I could take on from here to hopefully have this sorted.

Thanks in advance for any of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this was a very beginner mistake.

To anyone who comes across this and has the same issue, all you need to do is unwrap UVs for your mesh and tutorials on this are plenty!